# What was Boeing's competitor to the C-5?

Tags: aviation-history, boeing, lockheed-c-5

Doing some of my airplane learning, I have come across a point many times that the engines for the Boeing 747 (at least partially) came from Boeing's competitor to the C-5 Galaxy. What was this plane that Boeing had made to compete with the C-5?

Comment: I'm not getting this question, the C-5 is military and the 747 is civilian. Closest thing is the C-17 GlobeMaster III I think.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am asking about Boeing's competitor for the C-5 contract before the C-5 was. It is just like the YF-23 was the competitor to the now F-22.

Comment: According to the book [*The C-5A Scandal*](http://www.amazon.com/The-C-5A-Scandal-Boondoggle-Military-Industrial/dp/B001RBDLG6) the 747 came out of Boeing's failed bid for the C-5 contract.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In 1964 the US Air Force awarded study contracts for a new cargo aircraft to Boeing, Douglas and Lockheed. The aircraft was called CX-HLS. ( cargo experimental - heavy logistics system)

Lockheed won with the C-5A design. Boeing's design was never built but would have looked like this:

[image]

source: [Widebody Aircraft Chronology](http://widebodyaircraft.nl/chro1963.htm)

[image]

Source: Boeing archives

[image]

Source:[TDPRI.COM](http://www.tdpri.com/threads/since-were-on-a-roll-native-speakers-boeing-seven-four-seven-or-seven-forty-seven.563541/#post-6425836)

Comment: Based on the TDPRI link, it appears that Boeing called theirs the "C-X", which seems pretty darn generic...

Answer (score 13):

Boeing called the aircraft CX-HLS( Cargo Experimental - Heavy Logistics System). It never entered production though.

The below image is of a scaled down model of the CX-HLS.

[image: Boeing CX-HLS Model at Boeing Corporate Archives - 1963/64]
***Source***: *Boeing Archives - Bellevue, Washington USA*

Details about the CX-HLS can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160801153125/http://airwaysnews.com/html/museums/boeing-archives-bellevue-washington-usa/boeing-cx-hls-model-196364/19149)